# Blob storing data/files based on arrival date

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My application dump lot of different data to azure blob storage. But sometimes the application  dump last weeks data today. For example July 1st data may dump on July 10th and Azure Blob store the data based on arrival time.  Is there any option in Blob storage to change this? I want the file stored on the date it created.

From the google search I found that this can be done with the help of adding metadata to the blob by Rest API. But anybody know any option or any method to achieve this from azure portal?.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want mean create metadata from the portal and not from API, yes is possible

When you select you file stored you can at the end add custom metada 
[image]

But if you ask to change the attribute Creation time, so no is not possible by the portal, if you want keep you'r original date, metadata or a table storage will be the better solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it with Portal just do as Mary mentioned and if you want to code with with it, you could use `SetMetadataAsync` method to implement it. This is the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.setmetadataasync?view=azure-dotnet) about it.

Here is the sample code:

```
const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

        //Create the service client object for credentialed access to the Blob service.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blobfile");
        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();//Gets the properties & metadata for the blob.
        blob.Metadata.Add("key", "value");
        await blob.SetMetadataAsync();//Saves the metadata.
```